# Algebra Polynomial modular inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a polynomial $p(x)(2x^2+2x+3)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$
I realized it is its own inverse by squaring it. If I was not so lucky then how would you solve it?
So actually my question is, how would you solve it without trial and error.

Comment: So you want to find a multiplicative inverse of $\;2x^2+2x+3\in\Bbb Z_4[x]\;$ ? Why don't you write **clearly** that?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to my question?

Answer (score 0):

To find a multiplicative inverse of $2r(X)+1$ for *any* polynomial $r(X)$ over $\Bbb{Z}_4$, the simplest way is to square it to get $4(r(X))^2+4r(X)+1=1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_4[X]$.  In particular,
$$(2x^2+2x+3)^2=[2(\cdots)+1]^2=1 \quad\text{in }\Bbb{Z}_4[X].$$

You can try setting $p(X)=2s(X)+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}$, if you want to torture yourself with a tedious elementary [algebra-precalculus](/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) exercise.
$$(2r(X)+1)(2s(X)+\epsilon)=2\epsilon r(X)+2s(X)+\epsilon$$
Note that in $\Bbb{Z}_4[X]$, both $2+2$ and $2-2$ vanish, so as long as $s(X)$ is a copy of $r(X)$, the first two terms on the right-hand side will cancel out, leaving $\epsilon$ behind.  To make $p(X)$ a multiplicative inverse, we set $\epsilon=1$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, a polynomial in $R[x]$, where $R$ is a commutative ring; $$p(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0$$
is invertible in $R[x]$ if  $a_0$ is a unit in $R$ and $a_,,\dots, a_n$ are *nilpotent* elements.